# How to avoid duplicate records insertion in database table using stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a database table with these columns:

- Banner_Title            varchar(500)
- Existing_Banner_Image   varchar(500)
- Banner_URL              varchar(500)
- Banner_ALT              varchar(500)
- CheckBoxText            varchar(500) 
  [for these 3 checkboxes have taken chkArticles,chkFittness,chkHealthArticle

but I want to check  checkboxes also while insertion of data.For that I added one extra column in datatable named as sectionId for chkArticle checkbox I will assign 10 as a sectionId ,for chkFittness sectionId 11 and for chkHealthArticle as 12 so when I insert banner_title='article1', click chkArticle checkbox and fill other field data as mentioned in table format from then data should insert but next time when I try banner_title='article1' and click same checkbox then data not allowed to insert.but when I give banner_name='article1' and click another checkbox chkFittness it should allowed though the name of banner is same but maintained sectionid for checkboxes is different then what changes need to do stored procedure?? Basically I want to maintained unique banner_title for each checkbox click and to differentiate I maintained sectionid.plz help me

Comment: you could setup a unique constraint on both fields that would stop the insert but it would also throw an exception.

Comment: your procedure could check if the record exists for that banner_title and if so, update that record else insert that record. -- and as GuidoG mentioned, use a unique constraint on banner_title.

Comment: plz tell me how to apply unique constraint on banner_title .because I tried that but while inserting data it gives error as violation of unique key generates something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Create Unique constraint:

```
    USE YourDatebase;   
    GO  
    ALTER TABLE YourTable   
    ADD CONSTRAINT YourConstraintName UNIQUE (Banner_Title);   
    GO
```

Check if banner title exists before insert attempt:

```
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Banner_Title FROM YourTable WHERE Banner_Title =   
    'TitleYourAreAttemptingToInsert')
    BEGIN
      INSERT .....
    END
```

Comment: I edited question can anyone suggest me stored procedure to achieve this task??